# Как исключить некоторые свойства при серилизации

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Я пытаюсь сериализовать объект с несколькими свойствами, но не хочу включать все свойства при сериализации.

Конечно, я мог бы использовать атрибут `[XmlIgnore]`, но мне необходима возможность делать это динамически.

Вопрос заключается в следующем как исключить некоторые свойства при серилизации не изменяя исходного класса, при это хотелось бы иметь строгую типизацию.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сделать это можно следующим образом.

Воспользуемся готовым классом `XmlAttributeOverrides` но сделаем пару методов расширений для добавления строгой типизации:

```
public static class XmlAttributeOverridesHelpers
{
    public static void Add<T>(this XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> propertySelector, XmlAttributes attributes)
    {
        overrides.Add(typeof(T), propertySelector.BuildString(), attributes);
    }

    public static string BuildString(this Expression propertySelector)
    {
        switch (propertySelector.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Lambda:
                LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)propertySelector;
                return BuildString(lambdaExpression.Body);

            case ExpressionType.Convert:
            case ExpressionType.Quote:
                UnaryExpression unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)propertySelector;
                return BuildString(unaryExpression.Operand);

            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:

                MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertySelector;
                MemberInfo propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member;

                if (memberExpression.Expression is ParameterExpression)
                {
                    return propertyInfo.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    // we've got a nested property (e.g. MyType.SomeProperty.SomeNestedProperty)
                    return BuildString(memberExpression.Expression) + "." + propertyInfo.Name;
                }

            default:
                // drop out and throw
                break;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a member expression: " + propertySelector.ToString());
    }
}
```

применять можно следующим образом:

```
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var ignore = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true };
overrides.Add<MyClass>(m => m.Id, ignore);
overrides.Add<MyClass>(m => m.DateChanged, ignore);
Type t = typeof(List<MyClass>);
XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(t, overrides);
```

Решение было найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413711/5610621)

Comment: Во-первых, отметить ответ общим вы можете самостоятельно (но не вопрос). Во-вторых труд переводчика это тоже труд. Давно уже обсудили и решили, что переводы совсем необязательно отмечать общими. Автор оригинального ответа тоже откуда-то узнал, а не сам изобрел передаваемые знания.

Comment: @NickVolynkin почему то в данном конкретном случае поле в котором необходимо было установить что ответ является общим отсутствовало. сделать ответ общим мне показалось более логичным. Мы же здесь собрались не только из за репутации а например из желания сделать что то хорошее :)

Comment: да, я очень надеюсь, что репутация - это не главное. :)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам подойдет атрибут [NonSerializedAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: не подойдет "не изменяя исходного класса"

Comment: вопрос задал что бы опубликовать ответ найденный на stackoverflow, отметил тревогой что бы его отметили общим